# How to use Ajax for code igniter label

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My code-igniter web site has two label with radio buttons. 
[image]

When the load page, displays all course names. I want to make, when i click the button only show relevant course names. How to do it?

controller

```
public function index(){  
    $this->load->model('course_model'); 
    $course_data['course'] = $this->course_model->get_data();
    $this->load->view('ajaxtest', $course_data);      
}
```

Model

```
class Course_model extends CI_Model {
function get_data() { 
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('tble_course');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

View

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off">
    <span>School</span>
</label>
<label class="btn">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
    <span>University</span>
</label><hr></div><div><?php 
    foreach ($course as $add) {
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<p>" .$add->course_name.  "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?></div><script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code.
You have to add logic to categories courses you provide.

School
        
        
            
            University

---

```
    <div>





<?php 
//Looping course's
            foreach ($course as $add) {
                // check if current course is related to school, or universty
                $dynamic_class = 'school_course'; // if related to school add (school_course) class
                $dynamic_class = 'uni_course'; // if related to universty add (uni_course) class
                echo "<div class=".$dynamic_class.">";
                echo "<p>" .$add->course_name.  "</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
        </div>
```

Script for show hide courses based upon selected radio button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.toggle_course').click(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'school') {
                $('.school_course').fadeIn();
                $('.uni_course').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $('.uni_course').fadeIn();
                $('.school_course').fadeOut();
            }   
        });
    });
</script>
```